# What parameters do I need to pass to get_tags to get ALL tags for the site, when used in a post

Tags: posts, shortcode, tags

I want to show all non-empty tags used on the site in a sidebar next to the post. Currently, inside a shortcode-triggered function in `functions.php` I'm calling...

```
$tags = get_tags( array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'get' => 'all'
) );
```

...however this still shows empty tags, similar to setting `'hide_empty'=>false`. If I get rid of `'get'=>'all'`, then only the tags used by the current post are shown.

How do I show all non-empty tags, not just the ones used by the current post?

Comment: `get_tags()` doesn't return tags for the current post. Are you sure it's not just a coincidence that the current post has all non-empty tags?

Comment: oh it looks like my tags were created incorrectly in a post migration. They only appeared in one post because I had saved that post. Thanks for your help @JacobPeattie